# Getting "Task was requested to be canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled." when downloading artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have an Azure Release Pipeline that have many stages for each section of the site. When I trigger a deployment of a stage, I am getting the following error during the `Download artifact` task.

```
2019-09-23T12:09:03.6031363Z Warning, [https://mnxvsblobproduks147.blob.core.windows.net/931e14a2e7352bce/31458859BB32B321C84FD351B210300092DB62037E3B142D386F12E14DBAB22C01?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=qseDuph8BAjpX4zoQo0losEiFUxyATQij9ah%2FgnJyIo%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-23T13%3A05%3A48Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-48e869c0-e40e4a67-a92426ab-c05f9096-session-25a5fc50-22c34e0e-98c806aa-da9d37ae] Try 1/5, non-retryable exception caught. Throwing. Details:
2019-09-23T12:09:03.6033495Z Task was requested to be canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2019-09-23T12:09:03.6034154Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-23T12:09:03.6034633Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-23T12:09:03.6036978Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-23T12:09:03.6037616Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-23T12:09:03.6037944Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I have trying redeploying multiple times. All attempts have failed.

During the task, the error about is repeated multiple times, until is finally stops and fails the deployment. No one is cancelling the release to tasks.

EDIT:

I have deleted my answer as it seems that the issue still persists.

**Console Log:**

```
2019-09-26T11:26:28.0681165Z ==============================================================================
2019-09-26T11:26:28.0681420Z Task         : Download Pipeline Artifact
2019-09-26T11:26:28.0681560Z Description  : Download Pipeline Artifact
2019-09-26T11:26:28.0681714Z Version      : 1.1.3
2019-09-26T11:26:28.0681838Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-09-26T11:26:28.0682011Z Help         : Download named artifact from a pipeline to a local path.
2019-09-26T11:26:28.0682133Z ==============================================================================
2019-09-26T11:26:29.0048880Z Download artifact to: C:\AzureDevOpsAgent001\_work\r25\a/_STARS.Website/STARS.Website
2019-09-26T11:26:29.2564674Z ##[debug]Dedup parallelism: 192
2019-09-26T11:26:30.9982414Z Information, DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session e399dd1b-22fb-4cd3-aa41-0758dd47a55b
2019-09-26T11:26:30.9983220Z Information, Minimatch patterns: [**]
2019-09-26T11:26:31.0328832Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/nodes/A8D97BA7228AAE20B0FE0ECE0AC52E014E3BC8CD5B02D432E3B44306FB2E785F02 attempt 1/6 failed with StatusCode RedirectMethod, IsRetryableResponse False
2019-09-26T11:26:33.2275967Z Information, Filtered 1937 files from the Minimatch filters supplied.
2019-09-26T11:26:33.3003882Z Information, Could not initialize dataport.
2019-09-26T11:26:33.3085145Z Information, Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 193.7 MB (0%).
2019-09-26T11:26:38.3325414Z Information, Downloaded 4.2 MB out of 193.7 MB (2%).
2019-09-26T11:26:43.3365821Z Information, Downloaded 13.3 MB out of 193.7 MB (7%).
2019-09-26T11:26:48.3373240Z Information, Downloaded 29.8 MB out of 193.7 MB (15%).
2019-09-26T11:26:53.3488505Z Information, Downloaded 45.1 MB out of 193.7 MB (23%).
2019-09-26T11:26:58.3504653Z Information, Downloaded 63.1 MB out of 193.7 MB (33%).
2019-09-26T11:27:03.3632126Z Information, Downloaded 84.7 MB out of 193.7 MB (44%).
2019-09-26T11:27:08.3671176Z Information, Downloaded 102.4 MB out of 193.7 MB (53%).
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6866572Z Warning, [https://339vsblobproduks159.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/41CC140FD289554288048957BA1ED44DF9F6D21D7FB1DF101E60FD821A2A3F0D01?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=PSF1fWuZ1WWDhmpMXYk1tx%2FKq2vIz4Kq3Y2wmZzQyYo%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T12%3A07%3A42Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-85e9fc48-011a4eac-8d33ab75-b388547a-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. Details:
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6869596Z No LastRequestResponse on exception HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12152 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response'.
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6869911Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6871862Z    at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.StartRequest(WinHttpRequestState state)
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6874181Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6874874Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6875347Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6877636Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6877850Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:11.6878030Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:27:13.3696621Z Information, Downloaded 119.2 MB out of 193.7 MB (62%).
2019-09-26T11:27:18.3835506Z Information, Downloaded 142.8 MB out of 193.7 MB (74%).
2019-09-26T11:27:23.3953678Z Information, Downloaded 188.3 MB out of 193.7 MB (97%).
2019-09-26T11:27:28.4036023Z Information, Downloaded 191.5 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1679925Z Warning, [https://m67vsblobproduks129.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/A93E7808A0F5F613DC864C306BE6647CA067BEC3CAB3F138E8310592CDFDE1DE01?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=TDcv50VCf2FSJ7OKBPkiZ7AziZI3Zmx9yDGiKZo1f64%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T12%3A19%3A48Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-4ba7d224-93a74a71-ae0d368b-f82c59cc-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. Details:
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1680674Z No LastRequestResponse on exception HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12152 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response'.
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1680924Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1682696Z    at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.StartRequest(WinHttpRequestState state)
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1683266Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1683454Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1683990Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1684264Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1684461Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:29.1684636Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:27:30.6686757Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 failed with HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.', HttpStatusCode 
2019-09-26T11:27:30.6688149Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 throwing HttpRequestException with AttemptCount 1, LastBackoff 10000ms
2019-09-26T11:27:31.5551079Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 failed with HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.', HttpStatusCode 
2019-09-26T11:27:31.5551771Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 throwing HttpRequestException with AttemptCount 1, LastBackoff 10000ms
2019-09-26T11:27:32.4220129Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 failed with HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.', HttpStatusCode 
2019-09-26T11:27:32.4222717Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 throwing HttpRequestException with AttemptCount 1, LastBackoff 10000ms
2019-09-26T11:27:33.4049940Z Information, Downloaded 191.6 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:27:36.9845117Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 failed with TimeoutException: 'The HTTP request timed out after 00:00:50.'
2019-09-26T11:27:36.9845863Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 2/6 will retry after backoff 00:00:12.4010000
2019-09-26T11:27:38.4189051Z Information, Downloaded 191.6 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:27:43.4332930Z Information, Downloaded 191.6 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:27:47.2276758Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 1/6 failed with TimeoutException: 'The HTTP request timed out after 00:00:50.'
2019-09-26T11:27:47.2277808Z Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobproduks1.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A5eb5fc4a-85fb-4486-931e-14a2e7352bce/_apis/dedup/urls attempt 2/6 will retry after backoff 00:00:12.4010000
2019-09-26T11:27:48.4420275Z Information, Downloaded 191.6 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2536481Z Warning, [https://sqxvsblobproduks124.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/9662525A291BCAEE6A12CDA610B92E93C73AF87D3F0170C139C85AE17CC59F4E01?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=DnBLOaDR7SLzOqOCkT3Ohkbmbj6k7EBLxu5xzxFzDbs%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T12%3A17%3A39Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-a368391a-f7384cc6-b79fcf70-851f575d-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, non-retryable exception caught. Throwing. Details:
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2537360Z Task was requested to be canceled. System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2538454Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2538664Z    at System.Net.Http.WinHttpResponseStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, Byte[] buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2538875Z    at System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent.<>c.<SerializeToStreamAsync>b__4_0(Task t, Object s)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2539059Z    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2539891Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2540084Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2540272Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2540429Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2540598Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2540831Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2541015Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2541222Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2541679Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2552563Z Warning, [https://sqxvsblobproduks124.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/9662525A291BCAEE6A12CDA610B92E93C73AF87D3F0170C139C85AE17CC59F4E01?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=DnBLOaDR7SLzOqOCkT3Ohkbmbj6k7EBLxu5xzxFzDbs%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T12%3A17%3A39Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-a368391a-f7384cc6-b79fcf70-851f575d-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. Details:
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2553186Z No LastRequestResponse on exception OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2553467Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2553870Z    at System.Net.Http.WinHttpResponseStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, Byte[] buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2555073Z    at System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent.<>c.<SerializeToStreamAsync>b__4_0(Task t, Object s)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2555553Z    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2555836Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2556002Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2556193Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2556529Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2556755Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2557197Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2557430Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2557852Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2558194Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2558428Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<<HandleRedirectAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2560527Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:27:53.2561965Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:27:53.4539830Z Information, Downloaded 191.6 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:27:58.4604302Z Information, Downloaded 191.7 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:28:03.4679281Z Information, Downloaded 192.1 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:28:08.4838446Z Information, Downloaded 192.1 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:28:13.4935291Z Information, Downloaded 192.1 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:28:18.4992795Z Information, Downloaded 192.1 MB out of 193.7 MB (99%).
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7046259Z Warning, [https://ax4vsblobproduks187.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/EE8D20F5DFBC9F3AA5E76B4976B7AD74587F0BA539289FFE7A6FB69E887F012001?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=BEiWVHuXBEdAjaaQqfNbrDbBS6pReEwPurRQyPeixB4%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T11%3A57%3A58Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-2fa846e5-996446a9-b7d24076-018f4ca1-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, non-retryable exception caught. Throwing. Details:
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7047528Z Task was requested to be canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7048433Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7051142Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7051516Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7051698Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7051914Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7058076Z Warning, [https://ax4vsblobproduks187.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/EE8D20F5DFBC9F3AA5E76B4976B7AD74587F0BA539289FFE7A6FB69E887F012001?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=BEiWVHuXBEdAjaaQqfNbrDbBS6pReEwPurRQyPeixB4%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T11%3A57%3A58Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-2fa846e5-996446a9-b7d24076-018f4ca1-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. Details:
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7058561Z No LastRequestResponse on exception TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7058802Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7059058Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7059485Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7059673Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7059898Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7060071Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<<HandleRedirectAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7060223Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:28:18.7060418Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2198466Z Warning, [https://az3vsblobproduks127.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/0CD25F3BE7925E4A021F78E664888A2659C93A08601C3D10329757B7A7E0DF3E01?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=T09dUzB8ahTrVdaDrEUrFYxcHdbqF9GIOAOU8aXtomI%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T12%3A01%3A30Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-d91b6c16-683041de-878b8992-598e7138-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, non-retryable exception caught. Throwing. Details:
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2200052Z Task was requested to be canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2200927Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2201236Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2201483Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2201672Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2203863Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2208941Z Warning, [https://az3vsblobproduks127.blob.core.windows.net/db5eb5fc4a85fb4486931e14a2e7352bce/0CD25F3BE7925E4A021F78E664888A2659C93A08601C3D10329757B7A7E0DF3E01?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=T09dUzB8ahTrVdaDrEUrFYxcHdbqF9GIOAOU8aXtomI%3D&spr=https&se=2019-09-26T12%3A01%3A30Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-d91b6c16-683041de-878b8992-598e7138-session-e399dd1b-22fb4cd3-aa410758-dd47a55b] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. Details:
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2209470Z No LastRequestResponse on exception TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2209727Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2210002Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2210197Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2210395Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2210566Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2210770Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<<HandleRedirectAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2210951Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-26T11:28:19.2211150Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7872703Z ##[error]One or more errors occurred. (Dedup size does not match the downloaded size. DedupId: 259330FC2E8EB1AA1DEBF2A8E3DE3757E64A736C295B82FB45511D9A93C1346C01)
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7895364Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]One or more errors occurred. (Dedup size does not match the downloaded size. DedupId: 259330FC2E8EB1AA1DEBF2A8E3DE3757E64A736C295B82FB45511D9A93C1346C01)
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7962231Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7964700Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.TargetBlockExtensions.SendAllAndCompleteAsync[T1,T2](ITargetBlock`1 targetBlock, IEnumerable`1 inputs, ITargetBlock`1 finalBlock, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreClient.<>c__DisplayClass26_1.<<DownloadToFileAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<CreateNonSwallowingFunc>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreClient.DownloadToFileAsync(DedupNode node, String fullPath, Uri proxyUri, EdgeCache edgeCache, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreClientWithDataport.DownloadToFileAsync(IDedupDataPort dataport, DedupNode node, String fullPath, Uri proxyUri, EdgeCache edgeCache, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreClientWithDataport.DownloadToFileAsync(IDedupDataPort dataport, DedupIdentifier dedupId, String fullPath, UInt64 fileSize, GetDedupAsyncFunc dedupFetcher, Uri proxyUri, EdgeCache edgeCache, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<<DownloadAsyncWithManifestPath>b__6>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<CreateNonSwallowingFunc>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.TargetBlockExtensions.SendAllAndCompleteAsync[T1,T2](ITargetBlock`1 targetBlock, IEnumerable`1 inputs, ITargetBlock`1 finalBlock, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.DownloadAsyncWithManifestPath(DownloadDedupManifestArtifactOptions downloadOptions, IEnumerable`1 minimatcherFuncs, Boolean downloadManifestReferences, ISet`1 excludedPaths, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.DownloadSingleManifestAsync(DownloadDedupManifestArtifactOptions downloadOptions, Boolean downloadManifestReferences, ISet`1 excludedPaths, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.DownloadAsync(DownloadDedupManifestArtifactOptions downloadOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PipelineArtifactServer.<>c__DisplayClass2_2.<<DownloadAsync>b__6>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.Telemetry.BlobStoreClientTelemetry.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<MeasureActionAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.Telemetry.ClientTelemetry.MeasureActionAsync[TResult,TRecord](TRecord record, Func`1 actionAsync, Func`2 actionResultToTelemetryStatus, Func`2 actionResultToItemCountAsync, Action`2 updateRecord)
   at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PipelineArtifactServer.DownloadAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, PipelineArtifactDownloadParameters downloadParameters, DownloadOptions downloadOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.DownloadPipelineArtifactTaskV1.ProcessCommandInternalAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, CancellationToken token)
   at Agent.PluginHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
2019-09-26T11:28:20.8923191Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - _STARS.Website - STARS.Website
```

```
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7872703Z ##[error]One or more errors occurred. (Dedup size does not match the downloaded size. DedupId: 259330FC2E8EB1AA1DEBF2A8E3DE3757E64A736C295B82FB45511D9A93C1346C01)
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7895364Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]One or more errors occurred. (Dedup size does not match the downloaded size. DedupId: 259330FC2E8EB1AA1DEBF2A8E3DE3757E64A736C295B82FB45511D9A93C1346C01)
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7962231Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
2019-09-26T11:28:20.7964700Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.TargetBlockExtensions.SendAllAndCompleteAsync[T1,T2](ITargetBlock`1 targetBlock, IEnumerable`1 inputs, ITargetBlock`1 finalBlock, CancellationToken token)
```

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT, I updated my agent from 2.154.x to 2.155.1 and that seems to have fixed the issues. Not sure if that was the cause or not but I am not seeing those errors anymore.

Comment: Glad to know you have resolved this issue by yourself. Would you mind convert your comment to the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and find the answer easier, thanks.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have removed my answer as the issue persists. I have added the whole console log in the question

Comment: I have the same issue, but only related to a particular ISP. If e.g. I use a tethered phone instead of my usual connection, the issue does not reproduce.

I had previously found that reducing download concurrency via $env:VSO_ARTIFACT_TOOL_HTTP_CLIENT_MAX_PARALLELISM from the default 192 to a much lower figure e.g. 10 made the problem disappear. However the issue has recently reappeared, even with the reduced concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

> Getting “Task was requested to be canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.” when downloading artifact

Recently there is an resolved event of Availability degradation in Azure DevOps status page:

https://status.dev.azure.com/_history

Which may affected the release services. Thus please set variable “system.debug” in your definition of release pipeline to true, then create a new release to see if the issue still exists. If still have this issue, share the detailed log in your question.

Besides, this issue should be for the hosted agent, as workaround, you can use your private agent instead of hosted agent.

Hope this helps.