# Azure devops timeout when downloading artifacts

Tags: azure-devops

The release pipeline was working fine until recently, nothing had changed but it was saying that the agents were offline or disabled when they weren't. It turned out they needed to be updated from version `2.163` to `2.188` after this the pipeline would begin, but now it times out after downloading only a few artifacts.

What could be the issue?

EDIT:

The pre-releases `2.188.1` and `2.188.2` of the agents are allowing the pipeline to begin, but they timeout when downloading the artifacts. Anything before that version won't begin the pipeline. The last full release is `v2.187.2`

EDIT 2:

I have noticed that during a change to the release pipeline it automatically updates this property in the defintion for every task.

`"currentRelease": {"id": 3664,"url": "https://foo/bar/_apis/Release/releases/3664","_links": {}}`

3664 is updated to a new number in both places

When I reverted this change, these properties are unchanged and keep that version and the release is still failing to start.

Logs when timing out:

2021-06-22T10:32:03.0526533Z Task         : Download build artifacts
2021-06-22T10:32:03.0527316Z Description  : Download files that were saved as artifacts of a completed build
2021-06-22T10:32:03.0527728Z Version      : 1.189.0
2021-06-22T10:32:03.0528349Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-06-22T10:32:03.0529128Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts
2021-06-22T10:32:03.0529670Z ==============================================================================
2021-06-22T10:32:04.5890571Z Download from the specified build: #7588
2021-06-22T10:32:04.6009135Z Download artifact to: D:\B\4\r1\a/CI-Master/
2021-06-22T10:32:09.9551492Z Start downloading FCS artifact- drop
2021-06-22T10:32:09.9555929Z Minimatch patterns: [**]

2021-06-22T10:32:34.2488452Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/foo

2021-06-22T10:32:34.2544775Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/bar

2021-06-22T10:32:34.2552426Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/foo

2021-06-22T10:32:34.4205359Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/bar

2021-06-22T10:32:34.4232934Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/foo

2021-06-22T10:32:34.4298593Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/bar

2021-06-22T10:32:34.4710656Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/foo

2021-06-22T10:32:34.4722254Z Downloading: D:\B\4\r1\a/bar

EDIT 3:

There was another pre-release `2.188.3` since using this one I get these error messages in the log when trying to download the artifacts:

[https://a45vsblobproduks133.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/FCEBC807EB275E589526A319F580BE1B820DBCBB851D7E81C0E2BADDCC81783802?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:59:37Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-de94b040-568b459c-8cda94e5-026534ed-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://efcvsblobproduks136.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/BDC14BEB4450AF1EE289CEA5F6B6CC274C8001913AE60F90848E41A0C557965502?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:52:13Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-d318c08f-5f3148e4-a0411ef3-c2bcfb72-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://n5tvsblobproduks163.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/B078AA0E6EDECA41E40653102F86D48A272C221DEB4628C4CDBA440257C3079102?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:50:39Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-c4e45f8a-d9f54f42-b607074d-a31fd556-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://e9bvsblobproduks184.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/3B33EC397D2EDD7B9D78264333B7278932B32C208D969E3C8292350E2C6A7C8002?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:36:57Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-14dabff3-f7f04eb4-981bebb4-43531bd4-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://bipvsblobproduks176.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/8C234856A821AF42832040AD4B84FA11247E56C61FAA030F59B72AE96B5EF0DA02?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:46:26Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-b27f132d-33f545f9-b27d072b-ce6646a4-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://35rvsblobproduks146.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/D2FA706A53F22231B91D578430E9C3EAA837904E8874F774D1C65F83700401CC02?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:54:41Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-7c1cedd2-c5154bd9-b9e8f474-b46ca697-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://pubvsblobproduks130.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/08830F9C5398685A635B5B689C6D6A77E76E37CCFEE38313C611D22868E45B3702?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T10:01:00Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-829fca95-c1c743b5-b8ec857a-94a72dab-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://e56vsblobproduks19.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/63D246F0DA6625164C85C92B1724DDA1C38CC2273971AB1542201D7016C17CF702?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:41:43Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-a5abdf02-304a4aad-8d866aac-1bc0dd5d-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://a45vsblobproduks133.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/FCEBC807EB275E589526A319F580BE1B820DBCBB851D7E81C0E2BADDCC81783802?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:59:37Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-de94b040-568b459c-8cda94e5-026534ed-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://efcvsblobproduks136.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/BDC14BEB4450AF1EE289CEA5F6B6CC274C8001913AE60F90848E41A0C557965502?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:52:13Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-d318c08f-5f3148e4-a0411ef3-c2bcfb72-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://e9bvsblobproduks184.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/3B33EC397D2EDD7B9D78264333B7278932B32C208D969E3C8292350E2C6A7C8002?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:36:57Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-14dabff3-f7f04eb4-981bebb4-43531bd4-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://n5tvsblobproduks163.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/B078AA0E6EDECA41E40653102F86D48A272C221DEB4628C4CDBA440257C3079102?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:50:39Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-c4e45f8a-d9f54f42-b607074d-a31fd556-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://35rvsblobproduks146.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/D2FA706A53F22231B91D578430E9C3EAA837904E8874F774D1C65F83700401CC02?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:54:41Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-7c1cedd2-c5154bd9-b9e8f474-b46ca697-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://bipvsblobproduks176.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/8C234856A821AF42832040AD4B84FA11247E56C61FAA030F59B72AE96B5EF0DA02?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:46:26Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-b27f132d-33f545f9-b27d072b-ce6646a4-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://pubvsblobproduks130.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/08830F9C5398685A635B5B689C6D6A77E76E37CCFEE38313C611D22868E45B3702?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T10:01:00Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-829fca95-c1c743b5-b8ec857a-94a72dab-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://e56vsblobproduks19.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/63D246F0DA6625164C85C92B1724DDA1C38CC2273971AB1542201D7016C17CF702?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:41:43Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-a5abdf02-304a4aad-8d866aac-1bc0dd5d-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 4/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://a45vsblobproduks133.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/FCEBC807EB275E589526A319F580BE1B820DBCBB851D7E81C0E2BADDCC81783802?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:59:37Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-de94b040-568b459c-8cda94e5-026534ed-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://n5tvsblobproduks163.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/B078AA0E6EDECA41E40653102F86D48A272C221DEB4628C4CDBA440257C3079102?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:50:39Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-c4e45f8a-d9f54f42-b607074d-a31fd556-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://efcvsblobproduks136.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/BDC14BEB4450AF1EE289CEA5F6B6CC274C8001913AE60F90848E41A0C557965502?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:52:13Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-d318c08f-5f3148e4-a0411ef3-c2bcfb72-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://e9bvsblobproduks184.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/3B33EC397D2EDD7B9D78264333B7278932B32C208D969E3C8292350E2C6A7C8002?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:36:57Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-14dabff3-f7f04eb4-981bebb4-43531bd4-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://bipvsblobproduks176.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/8C234856A821AF42832040AD4B84FA11247E56C61FAA030F59B72AE96B5EF0DA02?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:46:26Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-b27f132d-33f545f9-b27d072b-ce6646a4-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://35rvsblobproduks146.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/D2FA706A53F22231B91D578430E9C3EAA837904E8874F774D1C65F83700401CC02?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:54:41Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-7c1cedd2-c5154bd9-b9e8f474-b46ca697-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://pubvsblobproduks130.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/08830F9C5398685A635B5B689C6D6A77E76E37CCFEE38313C611D22868E45B3702?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T10:01:00Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-829fca95-c1c743b5-b8ec857a-94a72dab-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
[https://e56vsblobproduks19.blob.core.windows.net/db3e0237a17a774f58bb16e2c2f11aea06/63D246F0DA6625164C85C92B1724DDA1C38CC2273971AB1542201D7016C17CF702?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-06-25T09:41:43Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-a5abdf02-304a4aad-8d866aac-1bc0dd5d-session-21903563-37d34744-8179a8e6-c0d8f1a5] Try 3/5, Task was requested to be canceled.

Comment: Are your agents Microsoft cloud agents or self-hosted?

Comment: self-hosted agents

Comment: We were seeing something similar up until a couple of weeks ago, when some traffic shaping was applied to the internet link.  Our build agents saturated our external connection when downloading from / uploading to Azure DevOps which caused all sorts of problems, including random failures to download packages, artifacts and even upload test results during builds.

Comment: okay, do you have any suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: Can you post the job run logs of timeout?

Comment: There was degraded service, could this have affected you? https://status.dev.azure.com/_history

Comment: The other suggestion I've seen on SO was "set variable “system.debug” in your definition of release pipeline to true, then create a new release to see if the issue still exists" - perhaps there's clues in that output? (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062247/getting-task-was-requested-to-be-canceled-system-threading-tasks-taskcancelede)

Comment: @antonyh I think the degraded service is likely the problem, I will go through the list of requirements and hopefully that fixes the issue. Thank you